# Lookup previous date for the same item in an unsorted table

Tags: excel, formula

Trying to create a way to QC daily data before pulling it into Spotfire to automate a monthly report. The data is sourced from the field so the data quality isn't the greatest. Plus some days get missed because there wasn't a guy working in the area that day.

I tried doing all of the calculations in Spotfire and managed to get it but after talking to some folks when I was asking about ways to QC the data. They all suggested doing the calculations, data cleaning, and QCing in Excel before pulling it into Spotfire.

Not sure how to put a table in here but are the important columns.

```
Column A: unique well identifier 
Column G: hours and value that I want to lookup
Column I: date
```

I managed to get all of the calculations and filtering completed within Spotfire but am wanting to replicate them in Excel.

The first thing I am trying to do is pull the previous dates HOURS value (Column H). Some wells will have a value on the previous date and some might not.

The below formulas are a few that I tried out:

- Formula 1: `=DATE(YEAR(DATA!$I2),MONTH(DATA!$I2),DAY(DATA!$I2)-1)`
- Formula 2: `=INDEX(A:I,MATCH(1,(I:I=DATA!$I2)*(A:A=DATA!$A2),1),9)`

**Results:**

- Formula 1 always yielded the previous day which would work for 99% of
  the cases.
- Formula 2 yielded `#N/A`

Comment: To post a table here, try using the [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

Comment: Can you clarify what is QC please? For me atm it stands for Quebec...

Comment: QC = quality control.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you don't want to do the whole thing using Spotfire.

Here is an example of an expression, using Spotfire, to get the previous date (which seems to be what you want, but without a dataset it is hard to figure out) :

```
Min([Date_Col]) OVER (Previous([Date_Col]))
```

You may want to use the DatePart function first to only have the date if you currently have a datetime

Comment: I guess I'm just more comfortable with Spotfire. I want to have the final visualization there since I can use the Automation Services to automate sending out emails.

Comment: @Tony Sure, but nothing prevent you to have the final visualization inside Spotfire. You don't have to display this calculated column. The computation will be run by the Automation Services so no problem with this.